# How do I let google index my table of contents?

Tags: seo

I am not sure my title is correct or not since I have no idea on SEO. What I want to do is, let google show extra links of my website just like yahoo.com.

When you search 'yahoo' on google, google shows Mail, Games, My Yahoo, Messenger, Finanace, Fantasy, Sports, and Movies. How do I add these extra links on my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is determined automatically by Google.  You may influence this by having is a good structure for your site.

Also submit you sitemap to the serach Engines.

I think you most definitely want to use the [Google Webmasters Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/)

Comment: This will not be determined automatically...  The OP has to manually submit the sitemap for consideration.

Comment: Submitting a sitemap does not guarantee Google will Display your Menu.  It's mostly determined by Google's Alogrithm.

Comment: True, but in all the reading I can find, you have to provide the sitemap for it to be considered.

Comment: I (may) stand corrected...  http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/ui-fun-better-snippets/

Comment: I do stand corrected... http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334 (-1 for me)

Answer (score 0):

These links are called Sitelinks.  To get them:

1. Increase your page rank
2. Google will create the links automatically

If you don't like the links Google created, you can block them using the Webmaster tools.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334